# What does clear_page_c do?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, profiling

During profiling, a see that most of the time is spent in `clear_page_c`, followed by `memset`. However, I do not know for sure what `clear_page_c` is.

I assume that `clear_page_c` sets all data in a page to 0 but I haven't found any documentation. The best thing that I found so far, is a quote from [this link](https://blog.debroglie.net/2011/10/25/cpu-starvation/comment-page-1/):

> The clear_page_c function is more worrying, it is a kernel function related to the control of memory. A web search did not reveal any more information.

Comment: If this is being called many times it's probably because your program is allocating lots of memory, and getting new pages from the kernel to hold it.  Possibly, it is releasing pages back to the kernel and then getting new pages and this could be tuned.  If the program uses lots of memory but does little computation perhaps this function being hot is normal behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the source to find out what it does, though it's written in assembly, not C. The short answer is, yes, it fills the page with zero.

http://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/arch/x86/lib/clear_page_64.S.html